# Can't connect to SSH after changing network card / public IP

Tags: network-interface

I have a remote server that always worked and booted fine. After I asked them to replace my network adapter my public ip changed and I can't access the server anymore.

Yes, I am using new IP on putty. I mounted the disk and checked `host.deny` and there isn't any IP there.

If I boot the server outside of recovery mode I can still ping it. My hosting company provides no support...

They just said:

> might need to change your network settings to match your new ip
>   address

The only firewall I had was UFW allowing port 22, never did anything to block acces based on IP or anything...

Comment: Your ISP changed the network adapter on your server?  What network adapter was it?

Comment: I don't know what was before. Its a Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver now

Comment: So this is like a server in a data center?  Are you ssh'ing "to the new IP address" in putty, or a domain name?

Comment: Is your SSH server attempting to bind to the old IP address?  You would need to check the `sshd_config` or the logs to see if that's what is happening.

Comment: It's a server in a data center. I'm using new IP on putty. This is my sshd_config on the disk... https://pastebin.com/WxDh2UwH

Comment: What does "I'm using new IP on putty" mean?  You're trying to ssh to the machine from putty using the new IP address?  Are you able to ping the remote server from the machine you're running putty on?

Comment: Try putting a web server on there, can you access that?

Comment: It seems you can access the system via a non ssh channel (maybe IPMI or a connection to the serial console). The first thing is to see if your networking is working on the server. These days most linux distributions attempt to have persistent names for their network interfaces, which is great until you change them! Can you ping **from** the remote server to something ( 9.9.9.9 is a reasonable address to try if you are not expecting firewalls to restrict access)? Next thing to try is to ssh from the remote server to the remote server - does that work.

Comment: I can access my server with "rescue mode" and mount my disks. And have KVM access but I don't remember my root password anymore... I can ping the server

Comment: Not clear if you have root access via say "sudo -i"  or "sudo -s" in the KVM. If you don't then I would bring up the server in rescue mode, mount the root disk in read/write mode say on /mnt and run "chroot /mnt /bin/bash". This should give you a root shell in your original environment. You can then run "passwd root" and set the root  password. Then type "exit" to get back to the rescue environment and reboot. Can you ssh **from** the remote server back **to** the remote server? Does "ps -ef | grep sshd" show sshd running?

Answer (score 0):

Firewall rules frequently include a destination IP.  Unless you're absolutely sure this isn't set in your UFW rules, and given your comment that you can ping the machine, that's likely the reason you can no longer ssh.

Comment: I mounted my disk on rescue mode. What I need to change there or to check if that's the issue? The only rules I have in ufw is `allow 22` etc nothing IP related

Comment: If you can boot the machine normally and access a terminal somehow, please run `iptables -S` as root and post the output to the bottom of your question.